# tsc compile typescript which imports using file extension

Tags: typescript, deno

I write my typescript code in an ecosystem-independent way. I decided to include file extensions in imports, matching the web and Deno.

```
import xyz from "./foo.ts";
```

How can I get the typescript compiler (`tsc`) to compile these files without the following error:

```
error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension.
```

I am so far tried the following in my `tsconfig.json` to no avail:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "*.js": ["*"],
            "*.ts": ["*"]
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: you don't need extension to specify, this much is enough `import xyz from "./foo";`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I know, but I have written my code with extensions, following how [Deno](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/typescript) (the new TypeScript runtime) handles import statements.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath this is wrong — ES6 import requires the correct filename, so producing javascript with the file extension omitted means this is code that will not run without further transpilation.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile without the errors by telling `tsc` to ignore all such `import` statements.

```js
// @ts-ignore
import xyz from "./foo.ts";
```

To understand why you cannot config your way out of it, we have to dig into the underlying reasons of why TypeScript does not want you to use the `.ts` extension inside of `import` statement.

`tsc` does not rewrite the module filenames so if you give it

```js
import xyz from "./foo.ts"
```

it does not produce a `foo.js` file, and the resulting compiled ECMAScript (of whatever version you specify) still says to import `./module.ts`.  Since the point of compiling to ECMAScript is to get rid of the TypeScript files, referencing a `.ts` file in the output is clearly not good.

What you want has been brought up in the TypeScript GitHub issues (see [#27481](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27481), [#11901](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11901)).  You may consider joining the discussion on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of why TypeScript wants imports to be that way, but with further build steps that could be fixed, if only typescript gave the option. In the end I decided to use the [compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) (currently in beta) which let's me do what I want.

Answer (score -3):

I am currently using the [typescript compiler api](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) (in beta currently) to solve this problem... i will post more details soon.