# Tsconfig: require file extension in imports (deno)

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, deno

Is there any way to require imports to include the `.ts` extension, or at least allow it? My typescript linter currently spits out this error: `An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './math' instead`, but deno requires the file extension to be present.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63289023/12769288) answer your question? Also, what editor are you using? in VSCode you can enable Deno support for a project and that will get rid of these error messages.

Comment: @Zwiers I saw that answer, but the idea of just //@ts-ignore -ing errors isn't really that satisfying of an answer. I will just install the deno extension, but it would be nice to just be able to do it via the tsconfig.json file if possible

Comment: If you use VSCode then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115527/how-can-i-avoid-the-an-import-path-cannot-end-with-ts-extension-error-in-vsco) might help as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using VS Code, install the official Deno extension and initialize it in your workspace by hitting `ctrl + p` and searching for the "initialize workspace" command. Be sure to set `deno.lint: true`

If you're linting from the command line, just use `deno lint` directly.

The official `tsc` will always complain about import specifiers having the `.ts` extension in it. There's a few issue on the TypeScript repo to enable this feature, none of which have shown any sign of being merged at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: This is available now in the official tsc by adding `allowImportingTsExtensions: true` to `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json